# Git Extensions is adding files without any differences to the commit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, git-extensions

Git Extensions has repeatedly added four javascript files to my commit. I have never knowingly edited these files and the diff for these files is blank.  So I don't know what, if anything, is being changed.

If I select the reset option for the files, they are removed from the commit list for a while. They eventually come back, but I have yet to notice a pattern or a particular action that triggers their return.

**What is likely to be causing this and what can I do to fix it?**

The files are:

- knockout-2.1.0.debug.js
- knockout-2.1.0.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: Possibly a difference in the newline settings between you and colleagues?

Comment: In my experience this is probably a line ending issue

Comment: also I would try the diff with this command: `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` and see if there are any files listed with differences then#

Comment: @SamHolder After running that command, it seems that you are correct. It is just a line ending issue. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a line ending issue. There was a difference in the settings for how to handle line endings between myself and my coworkers.  Correcting this difference fixed the problem.

The command `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` can be used to check for any differences that are not caused by end of line spaces.

Credit goes to @SamHolder for pointing me in the right direction and providing the above command.